# Power series representation of gamma function?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, gamma-function

I am looking for a power-series expression of the form $\Gamma(z)=b+\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$ where the $a_k$ can be calculated as some function of k.

Comment: $\Gamma$ has a pole at $z = 0$. Do you mean a Laurent series of the form $$\frac{b}{z} + \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} a_k z^k ?$$

Comment: It sounds like I DO mean that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\Gamma(z)=\dfrac1z+\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\cdot z^k,~$ where the terms $a_k$ form [this “beautiful” sequence here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsT4r.png). :-$)$

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: Is there a reasonable expression for the general term $a_k$?

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that $\Gamma$ has an especially nice Laurent series about $z = 1$.

Comment: @Travis: Could you please post its expression, or at least its few first terms ?

Comment: @Lucian It's a bit involved, and involves a sum over partitions; Wikipedia has it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General (Search for the phrase "has the following Laurent expansion in 1".) One can in principle use expand the powers of $z - 1$ that appear in this series to answer my above question, though the resulting expression produced this way pushes the boundaries of "reasonable".

Comment: @Travis: It's basically the same as the one I posted, only that it lacks the pole, and does not expand the expressions for $\Gamma^{(n)}(1),$ like I did in the link.

Comment: @Lucian Yes, that's what I mean by "expand the powers...", but the expression for the general term (of the series around $z = 0$) becomes messy if one proceeds that way. My question is basically whether there's a better way to write the general term than that.

Comment: @Travis: [Not](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.7) to [my](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma/06/ShowAll.html) humble [knowledge](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html).

Comment: I didn't know about the DLMF, this looks like a great resource! Anyway, perhaps this is another argument that the Gamma function should actually be defined as $\Gamma(x + 1)$ (i.e., so that it extends the factorial function).

Comment: @TravisWillse i can't seem to find the info on the series about $z=1$ in that Wiki link. Do you have another link? Thanks.

Comment: @Pixel Alas, it looks like it's been edited away sometime in the last five years. I don't recall the formula now, but there's a question here whose answer gives the first few terms: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287555/how-to-obtain-the-laurent-expansion-of-gamma-function-around-z-0 See also: https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.7

Comment: @TravisWillse thank you. I also took Mathematica for a spin: $$\Gamma(s-1)=\frac{1}{s-1}-\gamma +\frac{1}{12} \left(6 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2\right) (s-1)+\frac{1}{6} \left(-\gamma ^3-\frac{\gamma  \pi ^2}{2}+\psi ^{(2)}(1)\right)(s-1)^2 +\frac{1}{24}  \left(\gamma ^4+\frac{3 \pi ^4}{20}+\gamma ^2 \pi ^2-4 \gamma  \psi ^{(2)}(1)\right)(s-1)^3+O\left((s-1)^4\right),$$ where I believe the polygamma's are some function of $\zeta(q)$, $q\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I would like to know how the "beautiful sequence" full of EulerGamma's is derived. If you like I can create a question for it. I am especially interested in references showing how it is done, which theories/techniques are used. Thank you.

Comment: @niloderoock: As far as I can tell, it is simply [Taylor's classical series expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series), coupled with certain special values of the [polygamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function), which usually depend on the [zeta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

Comment: Thank you, @Lucian - I'll figure it out somehow, as I always do. :-)