# Gaussian integral via power series?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, power-series, pi

It is well known that the [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) is $\sqrt \pi$, i.e.,
$$ \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt \pi}2.$$
This is something we typically learn in calculus with polar coordinates.  We also learn how to integrate $e^{-x^2}$ via power series, e.g.,
$$ \int_0^t e^{-x^2} dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{t^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)n!}.$$
Hence one has 
$$ \frac{\sqrt \pi}2 = \lim_{t \to \infty} \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{t^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)n!}\right).$$

**Question:** Is there a nicer way to rewrite the expression on the right, e.g. with "only one infinity" involved, to get an interesting expression/algorithm for computing $\pi$?

Of course the goal would be "pass the limit through the sum" but this is evidently non-trivial as the tail of the series explodes with $t$.  My limited experience with analysis suggests one could try to split up the sum in various ranges ($n \ll t$, $n \approx t$, $n \gg t$) but that middle ranges could get hairy.

Comment: just a side comment: the value of the integral is also a consequence of the infinite product representation of sine due to Euler and it relation with the reflection formula of the gamma function

Comment: @Masacroso Yes, there are many ways to compute the Gaussian integral, but using power series is not one of the ways I am aware of.

Comment: because the integral is $\Gamma(1/2)/2$, and seeing [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352287/power-series-representation-of-gamma-function), then there isn't a "beautiful" power series representation

Comment: In fact there is a way to calculate this Gaussian Integral via power series, but perhaps not exactly the way OP suggests: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/gaussianintegral.pdf  (The seventh proof)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to changing the "upper bound" $t$ of integral,
you can make the integrand depends on $t$. This allows you
to get rid of the tail of the integrand for finite $t$.

For any $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$, let $f_n : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} (1 - \frac{x^2}{n})^n, & x \le \sqrt{n}\\0, & x \ge \sqrt{n}\end{cases}$$

For any fixed $x \in [0,\infty)$, it is easy to see $f_n(x) \le f_{n+1}(x)$ whenever $x \ge \sqrt{n}$.
When $x < \sqrt{n}$, we can apply AM $\ge$ GM to $n$ copies of $1 - \frac{x^2}{n}$ and one copy of $1$ and get

$$1 - \frac{x^2}{n+1} = \frac{n}{n+1}\left(1 - \frac{x^2}{n}\right) + \frac{1}{n+1} \ge \left( 1 - \frac{x^2}{n}\right)^{n/n+1} \implies f_{n+1}(x) \ge f_n(x)$$

This means $f_1(x), f_2(x), \ldots$ is a sequence of pointwise non-decreasing,
non-negative functions. Since its pointwise limit equals to $e^{-x^2}$, we can use [Monotone convergence theorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Monotone_convergence_theorem_for_Lebesgue_integral) to convert the integral on $e^{-x^2}$ to a limit of single variable:

$$\begin{align}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} 
= \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx 
&= \int_0^\infty \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) dx
\stackrel{\rm MCT}{=}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^\infty f_n(x) dx\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^{\sqrt{n}}\left(1 - \frac{x^2}{n}\right)^n dx
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n} \int_0^1 \left(1 - t^2\right)^n dt\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\binom{n}{k}
\end{align}$$

Comment: It will be difficult to calculate this sum for big $n$. What is your opinion? The problem is that the convergence to $\,\sqrt{\pi}/2\,$ is very slow.

Comment: @user90369 yes, the convergence is very slow. However, the point is get something out from what OP already has with as little modification as possible.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point of view. But: The OP also wants to calculate $\pi$ which should be possible in an acceptable way.

Comment: @user90369 To be clear, I wasn't necessarily requesting an efficient algorithm for computing $\pi$, but just wondering if one could get a reasonably appealing (to calculus students if possible) expression for $\pi$ or $\sqrt \pi$ from the standard Taylor series for $e^x$.

Comment: @Kimball : Then your text "algorithm for computing $\pi$" is misleading. Because a *noneffective* algorithm doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

An approach that emulates the usual integral way of finding the limit might be handy. Let

$$
A = \frac{\sqrt \pi}2 = \lim_{t \to \infty} \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{t^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)n!}\right).
$$
Now, we can write that
$$
A^2 = \lim_{s\to\infty} \lim_{t \to \infty} \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{t^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)n!}\right)\left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty (-1)^m \frac{s^{2m+1}}{(2m+1)m!}\right)
$$
However, the double-limit should hold if $s$ and $t$ are taken to infinity together - that is, if $s=t\to\infty$. So we'll write it as
$$\begin{align}
A^2 &= \lim_{t \to \infty} \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{t^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)n!}\right)\left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty (-1)^m \frac{t^{2m+1}}{(2m+1)m!}\right)\\
&=\lim_{t \to \infty} \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)k!}\frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{(2(n-k)+1)(n-k)!} \right]t^{n+1}\right)
\end{align}$$
where I've found the [Cauchy product of the power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_power_series) and noted that we can replace $t^2$ with $t$ without changing the result.

From here, we can use a [Pade approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) (with equal numerator and denominator orders) to get a result that we can take the limit of without running into convergence problems. For example, the first six terms of the power series I have provided for $A^2$ are
$$
A^2\approx \lim_{t\to\infty}\left(t-\frac23t^2+\frac{14}{45}t^3-\frac4{35}t^4+\frac{166}{4725}t^5-\frac{292}{31185}t^6+\dots\right)
$$
And the pade approximant $[3/3]_A(t)$, expressed with integers, for this power series, is
$$
A^2\approx \lim_{t\to\infty}\left(\frac{46193t^3+118860t^2+1742895t}{39266t^3+357819t^2+1280790t+1742895}\right) = \frac{46193}{39266}
$$
This isn't the greatest approximation (it's on the wrong side of 1, after all)... but if you increase the number of terms included, the approximation improves (somewhat slowly, though).

Note that you don't have to perform the Cauchy product to get $A^2$ as a power series before finding the Pade approximant, and you really only need the leading coefficients, which can be done relatively efficiently.

If you look at $\lim_{t\to\infty} [x/x]_{A^2}(t)$, the first 20 results look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The method of brackets can be used to calculate this integral,  just like other functions that can be expanded into power series. The relevant papers that will help are here:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.3356.pdf
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.2062.pdf
http://www.mat.utfsm.cl/scientia/archivos/vol25/articulo8.pdf

---

Here is a brief outline of the method

If a function $f(x)$ can be expressed in a power series as
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n x^{\alpha n+\beta-1}$$

Then its integral over the half real line is converted into a bracket series:

$$\int_0^{+\infty} f(x)\,dx \mapsto \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n \langle \alpha n+\beta  \rangle $$
Now, let me define the following symbol, called the indicator, as 
$$\phi_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\Gamma(n+1)}$$

In this method, the bracket series is given the value (also the value of the integral) according to the following rule:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \phi_n \, f(n) \langle \alpha n+\beta \rangle=\frac{1}{|\alpha|} f(-n^*) \Gamma(-n^*)$$
Where $n^*$ is the solution to the equation
$$\alpha n+\beta=0$$

---

As the function $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ can be expanded into the following power series
$$e^{-x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} x^{2n}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \phi_n \, x^{2n}$$
The Gaussian integral is converted into the following bracket series:
$$I=\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-x^2}\,dx\mapsto \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \phi_n \langle 2n+1\rangle  $$
Which can be evaluated by the rule I described above, where $f(n)=1$, and $n^*=-\frac{1}{2}$.
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$

Comment: Can you make this answer more self-contained?  What is this power series and how are you getting it?

Comment: I just edited my answer! :) How is it now?

Answer (score -1):

The Expression Can Be Written As Zeta Function and Zeta Function At infinity is 1 hence using proper methods it may be evaluated