# Behaviour of the Gamma function near zero

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, gamma-function

The Gamma function on the positive real half-line is defined via the reknown formula
$$
\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x}dx, \quad z>0.
$$
A classical result is Stirling's formula, describing the behaviour of $\Gamma(z)$ as $z$ diverges to infinity,
$$
\Gamma(z)\sim \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{z}} \left( \frac{z}{e}\right)^z, \quad z \to \infty.
$$
Is there any such approximation formula for $z \downarrow 0$, describing the speed at which the Gamma function diverges near the origin?

Comment: By the functional equation and Taylor's theorem, $$
\Gamma (z) = \frac{1}{z}z\Gamma (z) = \frac{1}{z}\Gamma (z + 1) = \frac{1}{z}(\Gamma (0 + 1) + \mathcal{O}(z)) = \frac{1}{z} + \mathcal{O}(1)
$$
as $z\to 0$. For a more precise statement, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1287555

Comment: $\gamma$ is Euler-Mascheroni constant. For $z\to 0$ we have $$\Gamma(z)=\frac{1}{z}-\gamma +\frac{1}{12} \left(6 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2\right) z+O\left(z^2\right)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Around $z=0$
$$\Gamma(z)=\frac{1}{z}-\gamma +\sum_{n=1} a_n z^n$$
$$a_1=\frac{1}{12} \left(6 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2\right)\qquad a_2=-\frac{1}{6} \left(2 \zeta (3)+\gamma ^3+\frac{\gamma  \pi ^2}{2}\right)$$
$$a_3=\frac{1}{24} \left(8 \gamma  \zeta (3)+\gamma ^4+\gamma ^2 \pi ^2+\frac{3 \pi
   ^4}{20}\right)$$

**Edit**

A quite good approximation is given by
$$\Gamma(z)\sim \frac 1 z \frac{1+\frac{\left(\pi ^2-6 \gamma ^2\right) }{12 \gamma }z } {1+\frac{\left(\pi ^2+6 \gamma ^2\right) }{12 \gamma }z  }$$

Comment: Nice. The last formula is very pretty. How did you get the closed forms for $a_1,a_2,a_3$ ?

Comment: @K.defaoite. Just series expansions.